# K&R Quicksort issue

Tags: c, qsort, kernighan-and-ritchie

I seem to be having a problem understanding where the issue is in the `qsort` implementation by K&R (C Programming Language second edition).

```
void qsort_1(int v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;

    void swap(int v[], int i, int j);

    if (left >= right) 
            return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
    last = left;                    
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
            if (v[i] < v[left])
                    swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort_1(v, left, last-1);
    qsort_1(v, last+1, right);
}
```

This is their version, I only renamed it to `qsort_1` so that I could use the built in one at the same time.

```
int arr_len = 9;

int main() {
int a[] = { 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 13, 17 };
int b[] = { 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 13, 17 };

    print_a(a, arr_len); // print first array
    print_a(b, arr_len); // print second array
    putchar('\n'); // space
    
    qsort(b, arr_len, sizeof(int), cmpfunc); // sort second array with standard qsort
    qsort_1(a, 0, arr_len); // sort first array with K&R qsort
    
    print_a(a, arr_len); // print first array
    print_a(b, arr_len); // print second array
    
    return 0;

}
```

`print_a` is a mini function for displaying an array, just one for loop.
`qsort` is the official standard implementation.

The output I get is:

```
gcc -O2 -lm -o qsort qsort.c
5 5 4 6 3 7 8 13 17
5 5 4 6 3 7 8 13 17

0 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 13
3 4 5 5 6 7 8 13 17
```

There seems to be a leading `0` and the last element is removed in the K&R qsort everytime. ...Help

```
void print_a(int a[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

If needed, here are the `cmpfunc` and `print_a`.

Tried googling the problem but no one seemed to have the same issue.

EDIT:
The code changed in the main function:

```
int main() {
    int a[] = { 5 , 5 ,4 ,6 ,3 ,7 ,8, 13, 17 };
    int b[] = { 5 , 5 ,4 ,6 ,3 ,7 ,8, 13, 17 };

    print_a(a, arr_len);
    print_a(b, arr_len);
    putchar('\n');

    qsort(b, arr_len, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    qsort_1(a, 0, **arr_len - 1**);

    print_a(a, arr_len);
    print_a(b, arr_len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: K&R does not define swap in the middle of a subroutine.

Comment: `qsort_1(a, 0, arr_len);` is wrong. The K&R version uses true indexing, not length, for both `left` and `right` arguments. The initial right-most index, therefore, is not `arr_len` ; it is `arr_len-1`. Fix that and the code should work as-expected.

Comment: What is `void swap(int v[], int i, int j);`? What is it doing in the middle of a function?

Comment: `qsort_1(v, left, last-1); qsort_1(v, last+1, right);` Maybe you wanted to say: `qsort_1(v, left, last-1); qsort_1(v, last, right);`

Comment: @Zakk that is something you do *not* want to do. The recursions should *not* include the just-placed pivot index. The calls are correct (except the one in `main`, as I noted in my prior comment, which is an off-by-one error on the right side).

Comment: @stark and Zakk in my book, the swap function is defined right in the second row, I was a little puzzled by that as well. I could take a photo and show it to you if you want.

Comment: @lukascobbler no need. It isn't wrong; just odd. C allows declarations (not definitions) of functions almost anywhere. Normally you see them as formal prototypes in global space.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes that makes sense, and it indeed is odd.

Comment: You are right.  I found my old coffee-stained copy of K&R and they do define swap in the middle of qsort.

Comment: @stark yeah, it's strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, look at the code ***you*** wrote.

- We can assume for a moment that K&R knew what they were doing.
- We can further assume that the authors of `qsort` in the standard library knew what they were doing as well.

Therefore, the first places we should look at what *you* authored. So what did you really author. The print function, the `qsort` comparator, and basically everything in `main`. A quick review reveals:

- `print_a` is certainly ok, provided the base address and length are valid (and they are in this usage case), so that's out.
- The `qsort` comparator seems correct, since (a) it works, and (b) it has nothing to do with questionable output from a totally unrelated function, `qsort_1`. So that's out.

That leaves only `main`. Within that function we have:

```
int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 13, 17 };
    int b[] = { 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 13, 17 };

    print_a(a, arr_len); // print first array
    print_a(b, arr_len); // print second array
    putchar('\n'); // space
    
    qsort(b, arr_len, sizeof(int), cmpfunc); // sort second array with standard qsort
    qsort_1(a, 0, arr_len); // sort first array with K&R qsort
    
    print_a(a, arr_len); // print first array
    print_a(b, arr_len); // print second array
    
    return 0;

}
```

From this:

- The array declarations are certainly ok.
- The `print_a` calls check out ok (base address and length are valid).
- The call to `qsort` is unrelated, and obviously ok.

That leave only one line of code in this entire program that could be the culprit:

```
qsort_1(a, 0, arr_len); // sort first array with K&R qsort
```

Checking the algorithm, the K&R function expects:

- The array base address (ok)
- The first index in the partition to sort, in this case `0`. (ok)
- The last index in the partition to sort. Um...

That's the problem. `arr_len` is not the last index. It is the length of the sequence. Since arrays in C are 0-index based, the last index is therefore `arr_len-1`, not `arr_len`.

Fix that:

```
qsort_1(a, 0, arr_len-1);
```

And the code will work as-expected.